# Beamerposter 36" x 48"

Tags: beamerposter

I seek to make a poster on Beamerposter that is printable on a 36" high x 48" wide laminated poster. I found samples on previous discussions in the site but I would like to be able to verify that they are indeed in the right dimensions.

Specifically, consider [this template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster). Is this 36" x 48". It sure looks like it to me but I don't know how to verify. Also, can I make the two middle columns into one column instead (so 3 columns instead of 4)? Thanks!

Comment: I would open up the template in Overleaf, compile it, download the PDF, and look at the PDF properties to see what the document size is.

Comment: @Werner I did try to do this, but I can't see to find measurements. Sorry for sounding like a noob.

Comment: Open the pdf with Adobe reader, then start to print it.  The requestor will confirm for you the size is 36 by 48. You do not have to print to see this.

Comment: @R.Schumacher I do not see this. Here is a picture of what I see: http://tinypic.com/r/e5fzw2/9

Comment: When truly desperate: \the\pdfpagewidth

Comment: @Mark Where should I type that?

Comment: On the first page of the poster.  Or the last page.  Or whatever.

Comment: @Werner: Your directions worked. The poster dimension is 48 \times 36 inches.